# CMake package dependencies handling

Tags: cmake

I am facing the current problem while using CMake:

I have `libA`, which I build using CMake and install it (in a custom directory, `~/install`, using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`) together with its exported targets and config (generated by CMake). The installed files look more or less like this:

```
~/install/lib/libA.so
~/install/lib/cmake/AConfig.cmake
~/install/lib/cmake/ATargets.cmake
```

I have `libB`, which links (privately) against `libA`:

```
find_package(A CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_library(B b.c)
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE A)
```

I also install it together with its exported targets and config (generated by CMake).

Finally, I have an application which uses `libB`:

```
find_package(B CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(app app.c)
target_link_libraries(app B)
```

The problem is that when the linker is executed, it will link against `libB` using the full path (`~/install/lib/libB.so`), but `libA` is only linked with `-lA`. As the libraries are not installed in any "standard" folder, it is not found (unless I manually add the folder using `link_directories`).

Am I doing anything wrong? What is the best solution to handle this case?

Thanks,